# How to combine to columns with identical missing columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two columns:

```
df:
Column 1 | Column 2
   1     |    NaN
   2     |    NaN
   3     |    NaN
   NaN   |    4
   NaN   |    5
   NaN   |    6
```

I am trying to combine them to have the output:

```
Column 1
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
```

The Code that I tried to use is shown below

```
df['Column 1'].fillna(df['Column 2'])
```

When I run this nothing changes. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: df['Column 1'].fillna(df['Column 2'], inplace=True)

Comment: try, ``df.sum(axis=1)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Column 1'].fillna(df['Column 2'])
df = df.drop(['Column 2'], axis = 1)
```